# How to hide desktop icons?

Tags: icons, 14.10, elementary, desktop-icons

After using ElementaryOS I am back on Ubuntu. In eOS one of the features are "no desktop icons" and "no right-click option on desktop" and i prefer that setting, its simple and lightweight and I don't use the desktop anymore, only for wallpapers.

How can I completely deactivate the desktop in Ubuntu 14.10 (like eOS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/), on the tweaks tab, there is section that controls desktop icons, and there is a button at the top to disable.

[image]

Note you will have to add the [testing ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-tweak-testing/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) as the stable version for 14.10 is not yet out.

Answer (score 8):

Open a Terminal (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type the following command to hide icons and disable right-click on the desktop:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

To restore the default settings:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

Tested on 12.04, 14.04 and 14.10.

Comment: Isn't `gsettings` preferable to `dconf`?

Comment: @muru: both are equivalent in that case, I changed my answer as `gsettings` is a bit more high-level than `dconf`.

Comment: @SylvainPineau Thanks but this only hide icons in case I run another file manager. I want to completely deactivate the desktop.

Comment: @samsy For me it deactivates right click and hide desktop icons. What's missing?

Comment: @SylvainPineau after using that command I did a copy&paste test with a random file and it still works to set a file on the desktop. I forgot to reboot, that could be the reason. Anyway the ubuntu-tweak tool solved it, too.